# Obtenho NA quando converto character para tempo (POSIXlt)

Tags: r, datetime, conversão-de-tipo, conversão, time

Por que obtenho NA quando faço essa conversão de character para POSIXlt?

```
    library(bReeze)
    data(winddata)

    tempo <- winddata[,1]
    tempo[1:6] # Preview 
    # [1] "06.05.2009 11:20" "06.05.2009 11:30" "06.05.2009 11:40"

    tempo_POSIX <- strptime(tempo, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
    sum(is.na(tempo_POSIX))
    # [1] 6

    valores_NA <- which(is.na(tempo_POSIX))
    tempo[valores_NA]
    # [1] "18.10.2009 00:00" "18.10.2009 00:10" "18.10.2009 00:20" 
    # [3] "18.10.2009 00:30" "18.10.2009 00:40" "18.10.2009 00:50"
```

Como se pode ver, os valores que foram convertidos para NA se comportam normalmente... eles seguem o mesmo formato dos demais.

Curiosamente, o erro NÃO OCORRE se passo um valor para o argumento **tz**

```
    tempo_POSIX <- strptime(tempo, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
    sum(is.na(tempo_POSIX))
    # [1] 0
```

As minhas informações de sistema são:

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
    [5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] bReeze_0.4-0

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: Aqui funciona sem problemas.
`tempo_POSIX <- strptime(tempo, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
sum(is.na(tempo_POSIX))
[1] 0
# [1] 6`

Comment: @Djongs, não entendi seu output... Afinal, o número de missings que vc consegue é `0` ou `6`? 

E o erro continua acontecendo comigo... Por isso editei a pergunta e coloquei informações do meu sistema lá.

Comment: Rogério, este resultado varia de acordo com a locale, por causa do horário de verão. O sistema do Djongs deve estar com outra locale. @Djongs para reproduzir o exemplo, rode `Sys.setenv(TZ='America/Sao_Paulo')`  antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No help do `as.POSIXlt`, há a seguinte passagem que destaca que a conversão de formatos date time precisa de um time-zone e irá validar este horário e que isso pode causar problemas em horários de verão (Daylight Savings Time - DST):

> Character input is first converted to class "POSIXlt" by strptime:
>   numeric input is first converted to "POSIXct". ***Any conversion that
>   needs to go between the two date-time classes requires a time zone:***
>   ***> conversion from "POSIXlt" to "POSIXct" will validate times in the
>   selected time zone.*** One issue is what happens at transitions to and from DST

Quando você faz o `strptime(tempo, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")`, você está convertendo o objeto para a classe POSIXlt.

```
class(tempo_POSIX)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Mas quando você faz o `is.na()`, você está convertendo para POSIXct. Veja que o método `is.na.POSIXlt` usa a função `as.POSIXct`:

```
is.na.POSIXlt
function (x) 
is.na(as.POSIXct(x))
<bytecode: 0x26519a14>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

O horário de verão no Brasil, em 2009, começou no dia 18 de outubro às 00:00. Isto é, considerando o horário de verão, não existe 00:00 no Brasil no dia 18 de outubro de 2009, pois quando o relógiou virou 23:59 do dia anterior, pulou automaticamente para 01:00 da manhã.

Então, quando você faz o `is.na()` você está transformando a data em POSIXct e esta conversão valida a data fornecida com a sua locale (que provavelmente é Brasil/São Paulo, pois como você não especificou a time zone, será usada a do sistema). E como não existe 00:00 do dia 28 de outubro nesta time zone, isso resulta (corretamente, mas inesperadamente) em NA. Quando você coloca a time-zone GMT ou outra que exista a data que você está passando (como Londres) , ele faz a conversão normalmente, por isso que funcionou com `tz = "GMT"` (e por isso que funcionou com o Djongs, ele deve estar em outro locale).

Comment: Sensacional, @Carlos!